# How to select San Francisco font using Interface Builder for attributed UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I have an **UITextView** with **attributed text** in which I want to select the new 'San Francisco' font for certain parts of the text. However, I can't find the font from Xcode's font picker.

Is there a way to select San Francisco or select the system's default font (as as I normally would if using plain text) using attributed text **in Interface Builder**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to download the font, then install/use it according to the guidelines:

> https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

WWDC video on the subject:

> https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=804

There's also a github repo that contains the fonts and alternative instructions (in case you don't happen to have your Apple developer account handy):

> https://github.com/supermarin/YosemiteSanFranciscoFont

<sub>*The font is still in a beta stage it looks like; use in production code at your own risk.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was a better approach.

Comment: The question asks about using the font in an app, but I think according to the guidelines you're only allowed to use the font in mockups. So is this answer actually correct? Or am I misreading something. I assume you should just use the system font which will be San Francisco on iOS 9 and higher

Comment: @TommyBs: This question was asked before the system font San Francisco was officially released, so it was a work around solution. Now you should use the official system font.

Comment: Is the official system font on iOS 9 San Francisco? Will it always be from now on? SF does still not show up in IB.

Comment: @Jonny: You will still need to download the font from the Apple developer site and install it. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense in my opinion, but that's apparently how they do things at the moment.